# "Поздравляю с днём твоего рождения!" Можно ли так говорить/писать?

Tags: фразеология

1."ПОЗДРАВЛЯЮ С ДНЕМ ТВОЕГО РОЖДЕНИЯ!" МОЖНО ЛИ ТАК ГОВОРИТЬ/ПИСАТЬ?

2. ДОПУСКАЮТСЯ ЛИ В ПОЗДРАВИТЕЛЬНОЙ ОТКРЫТКЕ (ДОЧКА МАМЕ) ТАКИЕ СЛОВА:  "ОБЕЩАЮ НИКОГДА НЕ ОГОРЧАТЬ ТЕБЯ, А ТОЛЬКО РАДОВАТЬ".

ГДЕ ЭТИ ПРАВИЛА МОЖНО ПОСМОТРЕТЬ/ПРОЧИТАТЬ.

СПАСИБО!

Comment: Буковки ваши не нечитабельные. Просьба: не так часто к ним прибегать. Та, что под цифрой 2, — в самый раз для обычного текста.

Answer (score 1):

"Поздравляю с днем твоего рождения" — звучит непривычно, но не вижу причин считать это недопустимым. 
В Нацкорпусе нашлось 4 примера. Обратите внимание, два из них датированы XIX веком.

> Бабушка нам дала платочки с мальчиками, вышитыми на них. Поздравляю тебя с днем твоего рождения!!! Пиши. [Феликс Патрунов. Детские письма с двумя штампами цензуры // «Наука и жизнь», 2007]
>
> *** Юрий! Поздравляю тебя с днем твоего рождения. Желаю крепкого здоровья, счастья и всего наилучшего в жизни. [Открытое письмо (1965-1986)]
>
> Прежде всего позволь мне Тебя от всей души поздравить с днем Твоего рождения и пожелать полнейшего успеха во всех Твоих начинаниях. [Великий князь Николай Михайлович. Письма императору Николаю II (1895)]
>
> Действительно, принимаю совпадение моего дежурства при государе (завтра) с переходом императорской Главной квартиры за Дунай к армии с днем твоего рождения за самое счастливое для меня предзнаменование. [Н. П. Игнатьев. Походные письма 1877 года (1877)]

Вот еще "с днем Вашего рождения".

> Как всегда, был рад Вашему письму, но был очень смущен и огорчен тем, что не поздравил Вас 26 июля с днем Вашего рождения. [Самуил Маршак. Письма (1950-1964)]
>
> Дорогая наша Галочка, мы с Ирлой поздравляем Вас с днем Вашего рождения. [Н. Н. Пунин. Письма А. Е. Аренс-Пуниной (1923)]

Comment: Спасибо за информацию! А по второму вопросу у Вас случайно нет ответа? И где такие подробности (что допустимо писать, что нет в поздравительной открытке) можно прочитать?

Comment: По второму вопросу: что-то там шершаво, но корректно ли в принципе — не могу дать уверенный ответ, поэтому молчу. Не знаю таких особых правил или рекоммендаций для поздравительных открыток.

Comment: Я благодарю Вас за то, что отозвались на мой вопрос! Спасибо